# maps api crashes

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the maps api tutorial in the documentation ( http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html ) to work, but it keeps crashing the emulator immediately before displaying anything.  I'm checked that the default maps app works on the emulator, I've cleaned the project, restarted everything, tried AVDs based on Google APIs 2.3 and 4.x.

Any ideas, suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added your maps api key to your manifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly change te geopoint creator line  like this.

> GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(19240000*1E6),(int)(-99120000*1E6));

than check the androidmanifest.xml and your api key and uses library

Comment: question: will having the wrong api key, crash the emulator before anything is displayed?  I'm pretty sure it's ok, because I copied it from the google site after i got it though.